# How to fetch data between 2 dates in greenDao database

Tags: android, sqlite, date, greendao

I have two dates . One is the current date and the other is 30 days back date. So I need to fetch the data between these 2 dates in Green Dao. But I am not getting the result.

MyCode:

```
 Date startRangeDate = new Date();
 Date endRangeDate = dateBefore30Days;
 QueryBuilder<StructSamePage> qb = UserDao.queryBuilder();
 qb.where(UserDao.Properties.dateTime.between(startRangeDate.getTime(), endRangeDate.getTime()));
 List<StructSamePage> list = qb.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try swapping dates you pass.

```
Date startRangeDate = new Date();
Date endRangeDate = dateBefore30Days;
QueryBuilder<StructSamePage> qb = UserDao.queryBuilder();
qb.where(UserDao.Properties.dateTime.between(endRangeDate.getTime(),startRangeDate.getTime()   ));
List<StructSamePage> list = qb.list();
```

Generally **between** works if left hand side value is smaller than right hand side

Answer (score 0):

The WhereCondition between in GreenDao uses this:

```
/** Creates an "BETWEEN ... AND ..." condition  for this property. */
public WhereCondition between(Object value1, Object value2) {
    Object[] values = { value1, value2 };
    return new PropertyCondition(this, " BETWEEN ? AND ?", values);
}
```

So you should just have to change your dates accordingly. Because you are using NOW first and the day 30 days before later your code would do this:

```
Value >= NOW AND Value <= 30 DAYS BEFORE
```

If you use actual dates wich greenDAO does not use! Your code would look like this:

```
today = 2016-03-04
30DaysAgo = 2016-02-03

WHERE dateTime >= 2016-03-04 AND dateTime <= 2016-02-03
```

So you should be fine if you just change your order.

If you want to know more about how BETWEEN works you can read [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/between.php)

A word of advice: greenDao uses timestamps as INTEGERS in the database so if you use java Dates you get a Date that also has a time (when it was created) if you just remove 30 days from it you will not include the whole day 30 days ago but only the day from the time the current date object was created in time. So maybe you want to create the Date from a Calendar without a time.